# AWS EC2 Java Spring Boot - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

Hello I am trying to run Spring Boot in a AWS EC2 instance and i am getting the following error:

Command in EC2: java -jar app-dal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.smartcommunity.smartparking.appdal.BootApp.main(BootApp.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Everything works fine in my local machine.

*Local Java version "9.0.4" - EC2 Java Version 1.8.0*

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.smartcommunity.smartparking</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-dal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>



    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.smartcommunity.smartparking.appdal.BootApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>


                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Steps I am following, using IntelliJ Maven Lifecycle:

- Maven Clean
- Maven Compile
- Maven Package
- Maven Install

Comment: Diff in java version should be the issue. Try running the app locally using Java 1.8

Comment: I ran locally with Java 1.8 and everything looks fine.

Comment: The error says that Java can't find the class specified. Open the jar file (it is a ZIP file and you can unzip it) and look for the appropriate included jar / class file. If it's not there, then on your local machine it's probably in your class path.

Comment: Remove your plugins and use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to create a proper executable jar. Also `mvn install` already includes `compile` and `package`

Comment: @M.Deinum this worked... thanks i just needed to add that plugin to the pom.xml and it worked... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Spring Boot it expects a special structure in your jar file. The [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) makes sure that this structure is created in the jar.

The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is specially designed and build to create executable jar files for Spring Boot based applications. So instead of your explicitly added `>maven-dependency-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin`, replace those with a single `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Basically this is al you need.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your output jar file from target repo to different location and execute it in your local machine. Let me know if you are facing any issues. In that case, we should modify the pom file to generated resources.

Sorry, since I am new contributor I can't comment you this in your question.

Comment: Hi.. Yes I am facing the same issue.So it means that if I execute in the target folder, is probably using the configs from those folders and they are not been package with the .jar file. Plz let me know how to modify the pom.xml...


`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.smartcommunity.smartparking.appdal.BootApp.main(BootApp.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Hey, the solution that gave in the above comments worked as expected... thanks a lot for helping to debug this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the pom.xml file as one of the configs plugin did the trick. Thanks to everyone who commented, the Solution to this problem and who came with the solution is in the comments. Thanks @M. Deinum